# Comparing dates in two columns and highlighting the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm comparing the two dates in the two columns (D and E).
The Dates in column D are source dates and the dates in column E are start date of the project.

I'm calculating the difference in two dates as weeks and pasting the result in the column F and highlighting it accordingly.

I have 4 cases with me:

- Case 1: If the sourcing date is > 4 weeks of start date then the status is *"Project delayed"*.
- Case 2: If the source date is < 2 weeks of the start date then the status is "*Project on time*".
- Case 3: If the source date is < 4 weeks, > 2 weeks of the start date the status is "*Project remaining*".

I have achieved the tree cases.

- Case 4: there is a possibility that in some cases the column E does not have any date and it is empty. In this Situation, I would like to have an if case, that says "*Project not started*".

I tried it as Null but, I could not figure out, why this case 4 was not working.

```
Sub dateCompare()
    zLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'last data row

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    For r = 2 To zLastRow
        zWeeks = (Cells(r, "E") - Cells(r, "D")) / 7   'date difference in weeks

        Select Case zWeeks
            Case Is > 4                                'later than 4 weeks
                zColour = vbRed
                zText = "Project delayed " & Int(zWeeks) & " weeks"

            Case 2 To 4                                'between 2 and 4 weeks
                zColour = vbYellow
                zText = "Project ongoing"

            Case Is < 2                                'less than 2 weeks
                zColour = vbGreen
                zText = "Project On-Time"

            Case Else                                  'in case of duff data..
                zColour = xlNone
                zText = " check dates"
        End Select

        Cells(r, "D").Interior.Color = zColour         'set cell background colour
        Cells(r, "F") = zText                          'set project status
    Next
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
End Sub
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.
Regards,
Mikz

Comment: Why not simply add an `if` statment before `zWeeks = (Cells(r, "E") - Cells(r, "D")) / 7 `? Something like `if Cells(r, "E")="" then zText ="Project not started" else RestOfYourCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
Sub dateCompare()
zLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'last data row

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
For r = 2 To zLastRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(r, "E").Value) Then 'check if column is empty
        zColour = xlNone
        zText = " check dates"
    else
        zWeeks = (Cells(r, "E") - Cells(r, "D")) / 7        'date difference in weeks

        Select Case zWeeks
            Case Is > 4                                         'later than 4 weeks
               zColour = vbRed
               zText = "Project delayed " & Int(zWeeks) & " weeks"
            Case 2 To 4                                         'between 2 and 4 weeks
                zColour = vbYellow
                zText = "Project ongoing"
            Case Is < 2                                         'less than 2 weeks
                zColour = vbGreen
                zText = "Project On-Time"
        End Select
    End if

    Cells(r, "D").Interior.Color = zColour              'set cell background colour
    Cells(r, "F") = zText                               'set project status

Next
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

End Sub
```

Comment: @Komal Rohilla did code help? Feedback is always welcome.